# HTML5 Fullscreen API applied to body

Tags: html, api, fullscreen

How can I apply the HTML5 full screen api to the body tag of a site by clicking a button and then a toggle button to return to browser screen?

I have been playing around but havent got very far.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that it's better to make the `<html>` element full screen, rather than the `<body>`, otherwise you lose the scroll bars.

```
<button onclick="document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen()">Full screen</button>
```

Obviously you'll want to test for support and use `mozRequestFullScreen()` on Firefox.